# Send data from PHP to an active Python 3 server script

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have a PHP script that accepts HTML form data and stores the data into a variable called $send:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
             $send = $_POST['mymessage'];
             $sendmsg = "INSERT INTO lora_messages (mymessages, yourmessages) VALUES ('".$send."', '')";
             $sendtopython = SCRIPT TO SEND DATA ($send) TO A RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPT WAITING FOR DATA
            }
```

I would like to send the data (variable $send) to a python script that is waiting for it, here is my python script:

```
while True:
    packet = None
    display.fill(0)
    display.text('RasPi LoRa', 35, 0, 1)
    # check for packet rx
    packet = rfm9x.receive()
    if packet is None:
        display.show()
        display.text('- Waiting for MSG -', 15, 20, 1)
    else:
    # GET DATA FROM PHP BELOW
        get_data = GET DATA FROM PHP
        sendmsg = bytes(get_data,"utf-8")
        rfm9x.send(sendmsg)
        display.text('Sent Message!', 25, 15, 1)
```

I want to get the data from PHP $send and have it set to a variable in Python3 called get_data. I can't use shell_exec because the python3 script has to run in the background continuously as its waiting for data from a LORA RADIO at the same time.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You might store the datas from the PHP script in a database and read it from python

Comment: @MelvynMarigny that is tricky as the python mysql connector is not great. I also don't want to poll a db for updates. I need something where PHP/HTML form sends the data to python.

Comment: @MelvynMarigny do you have a code sample on how I could poll a db for new values only?